# Auto Increment like with String values in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Well i want to know if there is a much appropriate way to tackle generating auto id with string values, my first idea is creating an auto increment id which we can call auto_id then before saving a new entity I'll query for the latest data inside the db to get the id then I'll add 1 to my auto generate value column that I assign name which is stringValue+(id+1) though I'm concerned on how it will affect the performance as to saving this entity needs two access in db which is fetching and saving... like my question earlier is there a much appropriate way to handle this scenario?

And also sorry for my English guys if you want to clarify things with my question kindly ask, thnx in advance..

Here's my code for AttributeModel for hibernate annotation

```
@Component
@Entity
@Table(name="attribute_info")
public class AttributeModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="attr_id", nullable=false, unique=true)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="attr_name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="attr_desc")
    private String desc;

    @Column(name="attr_active")
    private int active;

    @Column(name="attr_abbr")
    private String abbr;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="stats_id", referencedColumnName="stats_id")
    private BaseStatisticModel baseStats;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public int getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(int active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public String getAbbr() {
        return abbr;
    }

    public void setAbbr(String abbr) {
        this.abbr = abbr;
    }

    public BaseStatisticModel getBaseStats() {
        return baseStats;
    }

    public void setBaseStats(BaseStatisticModel baseStats) {
        this.baseStats = baseStats;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }   

}
```

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, but why would you want to use a String-based ID instead of an Integer or Long?

Comment: Actually Im not using it for id but for entity code.

Comment: @BrianJohnLee Can you show some code? at least entities?

Comment: hi @RAS I've edited my question and add part of my code i want to set the name of this attribute lets say str01021 with of course being unique.

Comment: I think you should not let it be auto-generated, at least not by the server.  Use a hashing algorithm instead, for example, guava and apache.commons.codec have some DigestUtils stuff to work with.  or add a field that is a long and let the db auto-generate it, let that be your id.

Comment: I'm sorry didn't follow you on that, to be clear I'm not concerned on how hibernate or db auto generate my id I want to create a unique name that is a string with int (or long) ex. str10001 and if my idea of querying the id of the last data on db plus 1 added to a string constant which is by ex. is "str", concatinate them to produce a unique name.. or there is a much elegant way to generate that? btw thnx for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only say "Don't do it". How is a String ID like `"str10001"` better than `10001`? It can't be an optimization as strings take more memory and more time. So I guess you need to pass it to some String-expecting method later.

If so, then pass `"str" + id` instead. Constructing the string on the fly surely won't saturate your server.

If not, then let us know what **you actually need** rather than what you **think** it could help you to achieve it.

I'm pretty sure, Hibernate can't do it. It couldn't some long time ago I checked it recently and it makes no sense (in any case, it's not a feature crowds would request).

Comment: hi again @maaartinus I guess I'm stuck in creating may own auto generate code which would be good if it auto-increment, but if it really is that trivial I will have to be content with UUID random value with date. Tnx again for the reply, I pretty much appreciate your answer.